# Dispose SPContext.Web

Tags: dispose

Normally it is not required to dispose SPWeb when it is obtained from the **current** context.

However what happens if I create the context on my own?

```
        SPContext spContext = SPContext.GetContext(httpContext);
        SPWeb web = spContext.Web;
```

In this scenario, do I need to dispose the web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to dispose objects hanging off an SPContext obtained this way.

If you look in Reflector, you'll notice SPContext.Current runs this code internally - effectively they do the same thing (which is to deserialize the context information which SharePoint stores in HttpContext.Current.Items).